# How virtuemart detects images belonging to a product

Tags: database, image, joomla, virtuemart

I have added some images to the product card. After that only the table #__virtuemart_medias was changed. So I presume that there has been added all information needed to bind the product and its images. Right? However I can't see it because there are not any fields like "product_id" or something like this. I see only field 'vendor_id' and:

```
virtuemart_media_id (AUTO_INCREMENT)
file_title
file_description
file_meta
file_mimetype
file_type
file_url
file_url_thumb
file_is_product_image
file_is_downloadable
file_is_forSale
file_params
shared
published
created_on
created_by
modified_on
modified_by
locked_on
locked_by
```

It doesn't make sence for me. Has anybody any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of information in your question was not enough .

Which version of  VM you are using ?

If you are using VM2.0 or above Then you can find a table name with `jos_virtuemart_product_medias` 
In this table VM keeping product id and media id. You will get all the images that assigned with a product from this table.

Hope this may help you..

Answer (score 3):

For Virtuemart 2.0.10

I got this fix after long searching and no solution so i came up with my own but crude anyway.
You can do this by  going inside     components/com_virtuemart/views/invoice/tmpl/invoice_items.php 
around line 74  create a new  tag   and add this code.

```
<?php
         if (!empty($item->product_quantity)) {

             $db = JFactory::getDBO();
             $qs = "SELECT file_url_thumb FROM #__virtuemart_medias WHERE virtuemart_media_id = (SELECT virtuemart_media_id FROM #__virtuemart_product_medias WHERE virtuemart_product_id =".$item->virtuemart_product_id.")"; //print_r($qs);
  $db->setQuery($qs);
  $item2 = $db->loadAssocList();
         foreach($item2 as $file_thumb){
            //echo $file_thumb['file_url_thumb'];
             ?>
             <img src="<?php  echo JURI::root () . $file_thumb['file_url_thumb'] ?>" />
             <?php
             }
          }

        ?>
```